# Next.js 13.3 appends txt to URLs when navigating pages

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, next.js13, app-route

I'm a student just starting to study the web.

[image]

I built a project with SSG (output: "export") for uploading to Cloudflare pages.

I am using Next.js version 13.

I used something called app routing, but when I build with SSG, I get "txt" in the URL address when I go to another page.

this is my first HTML
[image]

Inside the A tag, the address looks fine, but when you click to go to the page, it has TXT attached to it.

[image]

After I build the project, that txt file is automatically generated, and it contains this

[image]

I have some code in my script that seems to reference this, and I'd appreciate any advice on how to fix it.

[image]

I tried `npm run dev` and It works.

I've searched several pages trying to find something similar to this and haven't found a similar question.

I just want to make sure that when I do `npm run start`, it routes normally.

Answer (score 2):

Answer to myself

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48996

Downgrade `next` module version to 13.2.

and start it after build.

I think It's common bug in Next.js 13.3 version.

..이런 버그가 왜 있는거야 찾느라 엄청 고생했네

Comment: Seems to have been fixed in 13.4.7 (per the discussion linked)

Comment: for me i have the error only in production

Answer (score -2):

If you are just building a simple export static site then you can just use the "pages" router vs "app" router and the export works without giving you the text files and added scripts in the html.