# NextJS dynamic routes is adding .txt to the end of URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Error:

In **NextJS this link `<Link href="/link">link</Link>` will redirect to /link.txt

Now this is just an example, because for this simple link I can use just an HTML `<a href="/link">link</a>`

but the real issue is when using NextJS Dynamic Routes:

> src/app/stackoverflow/[questionId]/page.tsx

In my code I have a function that handles the redirection to this specific route:

```
function handleConditionClick(questionId) {
    router.push(`/stackoverflow/${questionId}`);
}
```

I also tested it with the link: `` <Link href={`/stackoverflow/${questionId}`}>Open</Link> ``.

In localhost it's working fine, but in the production server the router adds a .txt to the end of the URL.

NextJS Version: `"next": "^13.4.19"`

**next.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
    // Optional: Add a trailing slash to all paths `/about` -> `/about/`
    // trailingSlash: true,
    // Optional: Change the output directory `out` -> `dist`
    distDir: 'build',
  };
   
  module.exports = nextConfig;
```

**public/web.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
          <rules>
            <rule name="ReactRouter Routes" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url=".*" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next.js 13.3 appends txt to URLs when navigating pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76157727/next-js-13-3-appends-txt-to-urls-when-navigating-pages)

Comment: @MosheFortgang no i already read that question, you can even find my comment in the comments

Comment: He also mentioned in his question that it only works with `npm run dev` and not `npm run start`.  

_I tried `npm run dev` and It works.

I've searched several pages trying to find something similar to this and haven't found a similar question.

I just want to make sure that when I do `npm run start`, it routes normally._

Comment: he also mentioned that he had to Downgrade next module version to 13.2. but for now i'm trying to do my best to find a solution for next +13.3 or 14 that's why

Comment: @KA-Yasso have you found any solution yet ? Because i am also facing this  issue

Comment: @MuhammadSaqib & everyone the solution is just to update NextJs this has been fixed, and make sure that your application is running on Node Server, that why it runs on localhost without any problems

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

update NextJS:

```
npm i next@latest
```

the issue has been fixed in +next@13.4.7

the problem is only on production server and here's why; the localhost is running on Node when you run the application with:

```
npm run dev
```

which is not the case for most production windows servers
so the solution is either to install Node on Production server or leave it as it is and work with Query String **useSearchParams**
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params